# CSS Background Triangle 3 colors

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, background

I want to create a CSS background for a HTML5 section and it should look like this:

css triangle:

[image: css triangle]

I have already researched and tried stuff like transform skew or border manipulation. But i can t really achieve the view like i want to. 
Is any CSS pro here ? Would be nice. 
ps - if a bootstrap solution exists would also help me.

Greets

Tobias

Comment: paste your code Tobias, plus a fiddle if you can.

Comment: Currently i m testing around with that: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=gtLvKleAgB

Comment: you need to click "SAVE" and the give the link, otherwise you are asking me for a joint session.

Comment: thx dear Zombie its closed - got an quick answer - but really thx for wanted help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `linear-gradient`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  psdding: 0;
  }
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(10deg, lightblue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(-60deg, brown 30%, transparent 30%);
  }
```

```html
<div>
  </div>
```